# Set values to model by using string contains their names (mvc3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, model

I am quite new in asp.net mvc 3.

I have a model with some objects :

```
[Display(Name = "LowerHalves")]
public float LowerHalves { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "MCuleSize")]
public float CuleSize { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Diameter")]
public float Diameter { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Width")]
public float Width { get; set; }
```

In my controller I want to insert their values from an entity framework List .

I want to do something like:

```
 List<string> gradeParams = new List<string> {"LowerHalves ","CuleSize","Diameter","Width"};

 foreach (string param in gradeParams)
        model.param = lstd.select (d => d.param);
```

Instead of inserting to each one separately.

Is there any way to do it? and if there is - how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you setup EF to directly return you an instance of this model based on the values stored in the database? At least that's what EF is good at: map relational database tables to objects.

Comment: You have probably missed the point of strongly typed object oriented programming. Setting properties is a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As Darin pointed out, you should retrieve your model from your db through EF. After instantinating your datacontext you should be able to convert your table simply by executing .ToList() method.